# Set selected selected to the option

Tags: php

How to set selected="selected" for the saved option array below. Thanks !

e.g

```
<option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
<option value="Twitter" selected="selected">Twitter</option>



<select name="'. $id .'['.$order.'][url]" id="'. $id .'['.$order.'][url]">

                $socialicons =  array ('facebook' => 'Facebook', 'twitter' => 'Twitter');

                foreach ($socialicons as $socialicon) {


             <option value="'.$socialicon.'" />'.$socialicon.'</option>

                }

             </select>
```

Comment: What makes Twitter the selected option? I see no criteria that specifies this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have the sent value in your POST array at `$_POST[$id][$order]['url']` I think. Then it’s just a matter of comparing the sent value with the current value in the loop:

```
foreach ($socialicons as $socialicon)  {
    $selected = '';
    if ($socialicon == $_POST[$id][$order]['url']) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    echo '<option value="'.$socialicon.'" '.$selected.' />'.$socialicon.'</option>';
}
```

I am not totally sure about the `$_POST` array, so you might have to tweak around with that or search for how multidimensional `$_POST` is accessed.

If you save the selection somewhere else, e.g. in a database, you can compare it with the value from there.

Comment: I'll have a look, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multidimensional array to achieve this:

```
$socialicons = array(
    array("name" => "Facebook", "selected" => false), 
    array("name" => "Twitter", "selected" => true)
);

foreach($socialicons as $site) {

    $selected_text = ($site['selected']) ? "selected='selected'" : "";
    echo "<option $selected_text>". $site['name'] ."</option>";

}
```

The code above uses the ternary operator to create an an appropriate `selected='selected'`-text. Code not tested, should work - nonetheless give you some ideas.

Comment: @user2014114 Great! If any of the answers answered your question; please mark it as accepted (the symbol left to the answer).